# SilverlightL client enabled website, server disabled

Tags: silverlight, client-server

- Hello

I have a silverlight web application (Name : WebApp) where one feature is used for to acces another website (Name : TestWebsite).

The question is:

If that TestWebise can be accessed  only form specifical machines (in machine recognized environment) and if server where WebApp is hosted has no access to that website, will the client be able to connect to the TestWebsite from WebApp?

Edit: Machine gets recognized by it's IP adress to connect to the website (TestWebsite).

Comment: How arew you doing "Machine Recognized environment"? Are you using Client certificates, filtering IP addresses? 
Also, does "TestWebsite" has authentication enabled? Windows Authentication perhaps?